# Are there Android Code Templates for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a "standard" set of code templates for android development in Eclipse?

I realize I can make my own, but I'm just starting out and prefer to learn from other people's examples instead of making my own mistakes.

Comment: To clarify, I mean code templates similar to tab-insertion in other programs. I realize there are Java templates built in, but I was thinking about the XML for buttons, textviews, edittexts, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://raw.github.com/android/platform_development/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml

Answer (score 2):

Yeah there are standard templates, if you want to look at them then go to Window->preferences-> Expand Java-> expand Code Style then click on Code Templates, you can view and edit the standard templates

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are 2 kinds of templates for Java in Eclipse

- Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates
- Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates

Which kind are you looking for ?